# mysql select of rows involving csv

Tags: mysql

I have a table called txn in which a column called pid is a csv.
I am using query in the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM txn where pid like '%,11%';
```

ie.,if pid=,1,2,7,11,4 , then this particular row should be selected..
But my problem is..since i am using

> like

and if pid=,1,111,112 or something like this,then even though it does not have 11,this row will get selected..so this query does not solve my problem..
Can anyone help me with this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM txn where pid like '%,11,%' or pid like '%,11';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string always has a leading comma so add a trailing one too (e.g. `pid=',1,111,112,'`) and then `'%,11,%'` will always be enough. You can even do this on the fly:

```
concat(pid,',') like '%,11,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM txn where pid IN (1,2,7,11,4)

Hope that helps!